# Method not allowed - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, web-hosting

I am developing Laravel 4 application and just deployed it on a free hosting. The problem is that my POST routes are not working there and they are crashing with "Method not allowed" exceptions. The same routes are perfectly working on my local machine. Please give me some joker on what might happened here ?

UPDATE:

This is how I call the route:

```
$.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/store/addToCart/" + phone.id(),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).done(function(returnedData) {
                    window.location = "/";
            });
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/store/addToCart/{id}', 'CartProductController@addToCart');
```

This is my controller:

```
public function addToCart($productId) {

    $product = Product::where('id', '=', $productId)->first();
    //Session::flush();


    if( null !== Session::get('cart') ) {


        $cartId = Session::get('cart');
        $products_count = Session::get('products_amount')[0];
        $amount = Session::get('amount')[0];

            $cartProduct = CartProduct::create(['cart_id' => $cartId[0],
                                                'product_id' => $productId,
                                                'product_cost' => $product->price_bgn,
                                                'product_qty' => 1
                                                ]);

            if( isset($cartProduct) ){
                $products_count++;
                $amount += $product->price_bgn;
            }
            Session::push('cart', $cartId);
            Session::forget('products_amount');
            Session::push('products_amount', $products_count);

            Session::forget('amount');
            Session::push('amount', $amount);
    } else {

        $products_count = 0;
        $amount = 0;
        $cart = Cart::create(['status' => 'НОВА',
                               'cost' => $product->price_bgn
                            ]);

        $cartProduct = CartProduct::create(['cart_id' => $cart->id,
                                            'product_id' => $productId,
                                            'product_cost' => $product->price_bgn,
                                            'product_qty' => 1
                                            ]);

        if( isset($cartProduct) ) {
            $products_count++;
            $amount = $product->price_bgn;
        }
        Session::push('cart', $cart->id);
        Session::forget('products_amount');
        Session::push('products_amount', $products_count);

        Session::forget('amount');
        Session::push('amount', $amount);
    }       
}
```

This is working on my local machine, but on my hosting it crashes with "Method not allowed".

Comment: Please provide us with code you have used in your application. We can't just give wildcard solutions, that's not what StackOverflow is for. Show us your routes file, and show us the controller/method used.

Comment: Are you using the same route with get? If so try this for the routes `Route::post('/store/addToCart/{id}', [
'as' => 'addToCart.post',
'uses' => 'CartProductController@addToCart'
 ]);` and `Route::get('/store/addToCart/{id}', [
'as' => 'addToCart.get',
'uses' => 'CartProductController@addToCart'
 ]);`

Comment: No, I am not using the same route with get but added your code and it works fine. Don`t understand why, but works.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two routes for the same route you need to name them. The controllers and methods don't matter, they can be different or the same.

```
Route::post('/store/addToCart/{id}', [ 'as' => 'addToCart.post', 'uses' => 'YourController@postMethod' ]);
Route::get('/store/addToCart/{id}', [ 'as' => 'addToCart.get', 'uses' => 'YourController@editMethod' ]);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right... You *shouldn't* have to name routes differently for `GET` and `POST`. If you have two routes for `GET`, then yes you would have to name them, but not for different server methods. Odd.

Comment: Yeah that's not correct.  I just setup two of the same routes, one get, one post, and I was able to hit both routes without naming either.  Further, stackUnderflow mentioned he did not have a `get` route for this uri so he had only one post route.  My guess is he is using an older version of jquery where the ajax method did not have a `method` option and just defaulted to `get` so he really just needed to make his `post` route `get` instead or update jquery to something >= 1.9.